MS Word for Mac 2021: Bullet point formatting disappeared in whole document - how to recover?
I was working on a word document with multilevel bullet points, when suddenly I realised that all bullets had disappeared. See screenshot for excerpt of the doc after the bullet formatting has disappeared:

As can be seen in the screenshot, the first level bullet points were converted to style "Normal", all subsequent levels were indented by the same amount.
Three questions:

Is there any way to recover my previous formatting (other than reformatting every bullet manually)?
How do I avoid this happening again?
I adjusted some of the header styles (just the space before and after, nothing else) - might this have messed up my bullets?


See http://shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets20072010.html and https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/
